# Parsley.JS form validation not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, validation, parsley.js

I am trying to use `parsley.js` validation using simple form but is not working. My cdn is working correctly but I am not getting any validation. The code is:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
      <title>Parsley.js form validation</title>
      <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.js"></script>
      <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/parsley.js/2.0.6/parsley.min.js"></script>
      <link rel="stylesheet"type="text/css"href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
      <script>
          $('.parsley-validate').parsley();
      </script>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="span6 offset3">
            <h2>Parsley.JS</h2>
            <form role="form" class="parsley-validate" data-validate="parsley">
                <label>Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" data-parsley-required="true"><br/>
                <label>Email</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-type="email" data-parsley-trigger="change" /><br/>
                <label>Website</label>
                <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" data-parsley-required="true" data-parsley-type="url" data-parsley-trigger="change" /><br/>
                <input type="button" value="submit" class="btn btn-success"/>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean with "not working?" Any errors or something?

Comment: You are calling `$('.parsley-validate').parsley();` in the `<head>` before the form exists. Move the script to the end of the `<body>` or wrap it in a document ready - `$(function(){ $('.parsley-validate').parsley(); })`

Comment: ALWAYS use a DOM Ready event for javascript code. This will always lead to issues if you do not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you need to use the data tags to validate if you are calling `$('.parsley-validate').parsley();`. Look at the warning under this section on the docs: [Parsley.js Javascript Installation](http://parsleyjs.org/doc/index.html#psly-installation-javascript)

**EDIT:** I should have been more specific, you don't need `data-validate='parsley` on the `form` when also using `$('.parsley-validate').parsley()`. That is what the above link points out. Of course, you can still use data tags on elements to define validations.

Comment: Data tags define the validation rules. The problem resides in the function call before the element exists

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `$('.parsley-validate').parsley();` in the `<head>` before the form exists. Move the script to the end of the `<body>` or wrap it in a document ready:

```
<script>
$(function(){          
   $('.parsley-validate').parsley();
})
</script>
```